# Xrm.Page.getControl works in IE 11 and returns an object but the same code in the Edge browser returns null

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I've got a script which runs on page load and does the following.

===== start of js file======

```
var curFldCtrl = Xrm.Page.getControl("transactioncurrencyid");

function ResetFieldLayout() {

curFldCtrl.setVisible(false);

}

function OnLoad() {

ResetFieldLayout();

}
```

===========end js file==============

Funny thing is that this code works find in Chrome and IE11, but when I run it in Microsoft Edge, it throws an error.

There was an error with this field's customized event.

Field:window

Event:onload

Error:Unable to get property 'setVisible' of undefined or null reference.

Anyone come across this before or know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the variable declaration inside your function.

```
function ResetFieldLayout() {

var curFldCtrl = Xrm.Page.getControl("transactioncurrencyid");
curFldCtrl.setVisible(false);

}

function OnLoad() {

ResetFieldLayout();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work now. I'm going to find out myself but would you happen to know why? I mean why does Edge not accept global declarations?

Comment: @AndrewN, I'm guessing that Edge decided not to execute `Xrm.Page.getControl`. The variable declaration `curFldCtrl` exists, it just wasn't populated.